# Java gives an error if there's no blank line at end of Input file

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner, inputstream

I just have a weird problem while I'm trying to read from file into Java. I am able to read everything in the file as long as there is a blank line at the end of the input file. If there is no blank line, it crashes. Why is that?

I have figured out the problem is the blank line after a while. As long as the input file has a blank line at the end, it is fine.

Input File that will run with no problems:

[image: No Errors Input File]

Input File that will give an error:

[image: Error Input File]

[image: Errors]

**Notice the line numbers!**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileInputName;
        String fileOutputName;

        String firstName;
            String lastName;
            String houseNumber;
            String street;
            String city;
            String state;
            String zip;

            String productDescription;
            double productPrice = 0;
            double productCost = 0;
            int productQuantity = 0;

            int totalQuantity = 0;
            double totalCost = 0;


        Scanner input = null;
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("What is the file name?\n");


        fileInputName = input.nextLine();


        System.out.println("File name is: " + fileInputName);

        FileReader filereader;
        Scanner readInput = null;


        try {
            readInput = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileInputName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Header
        firstName = readInput.nextLine();
        lastName = readInput.nextLine();
        houseNumber = readInput.nextLine();
        street = readInput.nextLine();
        city = readInput.nextLine();
        state = readInput.nextLine();
        zip = readInput.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("Purchase Report\n---------------\n%s %s\n%s %s\n%s, %s %s\n\n"
                + "Description\t\t\tPrice\tQuantity\tCost\n"
                + "-----------\t\t\t-----\t--------\t----\n", 
                firstName, lastName, houseNumber, street, city, state, zip);

        while (readInput.hasNextLine())
        {
            productDescription = readInput.nextLine();
            productPrice = readInput.nextDouble();
            readInput.nextLine();
            productQuantity = readInput.nextInt();
            readInput.nextLine();

            productCost = productPrice * productQuantity;

            totalCost += productCost;
            totalQuantity += productQuantity;
            System.out.printf("%-30s%7.2f\t%8d     %7.2f\n", 
                    productDescription, productPrice, productQuantity, productCost);
        }

        //Footer
        System.out.printf("-----------\t\t\t-----\t--------\t----\n"
                + "Total\t\t\t\t\t%8d     %7.2f\n", totalQuantity, totalCost);

        readInput.close();      

    }
}
```

It should be able to read without the extra line right? Can anyone explain to me what is happening and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Well, after reading the last product quantity, you call nextLine() without first checking if there is a next line. And there isn't one. So you get that exception.

Comment: That makes sense. So should I make another loop for checking if there is a next line? If so, how would I go about it? I am new to Java syntax so i am not too sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `nextLine()` *after* calling `nextXxx()`, it will read the *rest* of the line, which is usually just the end-of-line character(s).

When there is no end-of-line character(s) at the end of the last line, it means you're already at end-of-file after the call to `nextInt()`, which is why the unconditional `nextLine()` call fails.

Two ways to fix:

1. Don't call `nextLine()` unconditionally:

   ```
   productDescription = readInput.nextLine();
   productPrice = readInput.nextDouble();
   readInput.nextLine();
   productQuantity = readInput.nextInt();
   if (readInput.hasNextLine())
       readInput.nextLine();
   ```
2. Don't use `nextXxx()`:

   ```
   productDescription = readInput.nextLine();
   productPrice = Double.parseDouble(readInput.nextLine().trim());
   productQuantity = Integer.parseInt(readInput.nextLine().trim());
   ```

   `trim()` shouldn't be necessary, but makes the code consistent with existing code.

Option 2 is recommended, because it will correctly fail if there is extra text following the numbers, while option 1 will silently discard such extra text.

Besides, the code is neater.

Comment: I'm dumb. You're exactly right thank you so much for the explanation! It's been weird trying to learn how Scanner exactly works. Thank you! :)

Comment: @ThatOneGoi My general recommendation is to not bother learning how `Scanner` works. It's slooowww, and it is difficult to get the error handling correct. Generally better to just read lines, e.g. using `BufferedReader` if reading a file, then process the lines using regex, if the line has multiple values.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! I will definitely look into that and use it for future projects!

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned in the comments, your final call to `readInput.nextLine();` bombs out because there is nothing left to read. In the earlier iterations, it was clearing out the rest of the line and probably any newline characters, but those don't exist at the end of the file.

An alternative solution is to simply call `readInput.nextLine()` for any line instead of `nextInt` and parse it separately with `Integer.parseInt`, for example.